# Notice: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' in ....functions.php on line 73

Tags: functions, menus, errors, 500-internal-error

When I tried to edit my menu, it appeared

> HTTP ERROR 500

Then I set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in *wp-config.php*

Once I try to save the menu, the following error appears:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' in /www/web/keenker/public_html/wp-content/themes/keenker/functions.php on line 73

The tricky thing is, my line 73 in *functions.php* is

> return trim($title);

And throughout the *functions.php* file, I don't even have `REQUEST_URI` parameters.

Appreciate for any help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/556833/378183 - looks like that PHP notice was occurring regardless of your 500 Error - you're only seeing it now because you turned on WP_DEBUG. The notice and the error are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Without quotes PHP interprets the `REQUEST_URI` as a constant** but corrects your typo error if there is no such constant and interprets it as string.

When [`error_reporting`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) includes [`E_NOTICE`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php), you would probably get an error such as:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' in *<file path>* on line *<line number>*

But if there is a constant with this name, PHP will use the constant’s value instead. (See also [Array do's and don'ts](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts))

**So always use quotes when you mean a string.** Otherwise it can have unwanted side effects.

And for the difference of single and double quoted strings, see the [PHP manual about strings](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/languag

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue myself by editing a line in functions.php and it no longer shows the error message for me. The error was:

**Warning: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI – assumed ‘REQUEST_URI’ (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/web33/web/wp-content/themes/slanted-master/functions.php on line 73**

So on line 73 in functions.php I changed the line mentioned in the error message to:

```
$path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```